# comparing h.264 encoding decoding performance

Tags: h.264

I am beginner of video codec. not an video codec expert

I just want to know base on the same criteria, Comparing  H254 encoding/decoding which is more efficiency.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding is more efficient.  To be useful, decoding must run in real time, where encoding does not (except in videophone / conferencing applications).

How much more efficient? An encoder can generate motion vectors. The more compute power used on generating those motion vectors, the more accurate they are. And, the more accurate they are, the more bandwidth is available for the difference frames, so the quality goes up.

So, the kind of encoding used to generate video for streaming or distribution on DVD or BD discs can run many times slower than real time on server farms. But decoding for that kind of program is useless unless it runs in real time.

Even in the case of real-time encoding it takes more power (actual milliwatts, compute cycles, etc) than decoding.

It's true of H.264, H.265, VP8, VP9, and other video codecs.